# Mac OS: how to fork without copying process state?

Tags: macos, process, fork, darwin, xnu

I need to create a unit of execution with a different PID, but does not acquire resources from the initial process (open files, memory, ...).

On Linux, [`clone`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) is used for this purpose. On other BSDs, [`rfork`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rfork&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+13-current&arch=default&format=html). Is there a Mac OS equivalent?

Alternatively, standard `execve` can be used to reset the process environment, but requires a name on the filesystem, which is suboptimal for my purposes. On Linux a [`memfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) can be created and used with [`execveat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execveat.2.html). Is there a Mac OS equivalent?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to execute a file that doesn't exist in the global file system namespace on macOS. I think that's what you're asking? (The only alternatives to `fork()` on macOS are `vfork()` and `posix_spawn()`, neither of which is any help with what you're trying to do, and the other `exec*()` variants on macOS are no more powerful than `execve()` itself.)

Comment: Yes, that was what I was asking. Sucks to hear it isn't possible but that is what I expected to hear. I think I can at least limit some of the damage by using `vm_inherit` & `VM_INHERIT_SHARE` on regions I allocate (not sure, I am not very familiar with Mac-specific system programming)

Comment: Yes, that should work for memory. I don't think there's much you can do about file descriptors, as you can only mark them close-on-*exec*, not close-on-*fork*.

Comment: One more option you could explore is using the Mach task APIs, i.e. `task_create()`, then manipulate the memory regions, followed by `thread_create_running()` to actually kick off execution. These are extremely low-level APIs however, and you'll need to do some extra work to get POSIX APIs working inside the new task. (e.g. you'll need to explicitly register the main thread as a POSIX thread) I don't know what happens to file descriptors when using `task_create()`.

Comment: It's a good lead, but apparently [`task_create` was disabled in 10.5](https://robert.sesek.com/2014/1/changes_to_xnu_mach_ipc.html).